# Remove azuread users

Tags: powershell

Trying to remove azuread\users in localgroup administrators

I, nor Atera AI, can seem to get it correct...

> Get-LocalGroupMember : Failed to compare two elements in the array. At
> localadmin.ps1:8 char:12
>
> - $members = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $localGroupName
> - 
> - CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-LocalGroupMember], InvalidOperationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : An unspecified error occurred.,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetLocalGroupMemberCommand

```
# Define the local group name
$localGroupName = "administrators"
# Define the domain name
$domainName = "azuread"
# Get the members of the local group
$members = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $localGroupName

# Loop through each member and remove if it is an Azure AD user
foreach ($member in $members) {
if ($member.ObjectClass -eq "User" -and $member.Name.StartsWith("$domainName\")) {
Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group $localGroupName -Member $member.Name
}
}
```

> Get-LocalGroupMember : Failed to compare two elements in the array. At
> localadmin.ps1:5 char:12
>
> - $members = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $adminGroup | Where-Object {$_ ...
> - 
> - CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-LocalGroupMember], InvalidOperationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : An unspecified error occurred.,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetLocalGroupMemberCommand

```
# Set the variable $adminGroup to the name of the administrators group
$adminGroup = "Administrators"
# Get all members of the administrators group and filter out any that start with "LocalAdmin"
$members = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $adminGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "LocalAdmin"}
# Loop through each member and remove them from the administrators group
foreach ($member in $members) {
Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group $adminGroup -Member $member.Name
}
# Output a message indicating the script has completed
```